# How can I load a string like this( {u'facebook': {u'identifier': u'http://www.facebook.com/71'}} ) into JSON

Tags: python, json, load

I got this string from another python crawler program.

```
{u'facebook': {u'identifier': u'http://www.facebook.com/71'}}
```

I have read the most questions about JSON. I know the question is about the single quote mark. but how do I convert it into double quote marks?

I have tried json.dump(), but it only add a pair of double quote marks of the string.

```
"{u'facebook': {u'identifier': u'http://www.facebook.com/71'}} "
```

I have also tried to use demjson, but the result is the same as above.

Actually I only need to the string behind the "identifier". How can I get that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really get the first thing as a dict? And what do you mean by "load into JSON"? Do you want to get the dictionary inside that string? In that case why don't you use `json.loads()`?

Comment: No, I don't. Sorry, I haven't been clear. First, the string is in a CSV file. so I think it is a string at first, I tried to use json.loads(), but it pops -------ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)--------, They say it's because it has single quote mark, which is inconsistent with JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string `"{u'facebook': {u'identifier': u'http://www.facebook.com/71'}} "` doesn't look like JSON. First it has single quotes (as you already found out) and it also has unicode prefixes: `u`.

That string actually looks like valid python, so you can use the [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function to parse it into a `dict`

```
from ast import literal_eval

dictionary = literal_eval("{u'facebook': {u'identifier': u'http://www.facebook.com/71'}}"
```